# Elastic aggregation to identify period A vs B percentage increases

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have some daily sales data indexed into Elasticsearch. I successfully run a number of aggregations to identify top sellers across a date range etc.

I am now trying to write a single query to do the following:

- Identify Top n sellers over a date range (Period A)
- Take the results of Period A and sum sales for these products over second date range (Period B)
- Compare sales in period A to Period B and identify those with percentage increases above X%.

My attempt so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2017-10-01",
              "lte": "2017-10-14"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "data_split": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date_periods": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "date",
            "format": "YYYY-MM-dd",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "2017-10-01",
                "to": "2017-10-07"
              },
              {
                "from": "2017-10-08",
                "to": "2017-10-14"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "product_id_split": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "product_id"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "unit_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "units"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although this outputs results for two periods, I don't think this is quite what I want as the initial filter is running from Period A start date to Period B end date and I think summing results for that range instead of Period A only. I also don't get the % comparison, I would probably do this at my application level, but I understand could be handled with a scripted Elastic query?

It would be especially awesome if instead of top n results in period A, I could set a sales threshold of say 1,000 sales.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Currently running Elastic 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2017-10-01",
              "lte": "2017-10-14"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "data_split": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 10,
        "field": "product_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "date_period1": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "2017-10-01",
                "lte": "2017-10-07"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "unit_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "units"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "date_period2": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "gte": "2017-10-08",
                "lte": "2017-10-14"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "unit_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "units"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "percentage_increase": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "firstPeriod": "date_period1>unit_sum",
              "secondPeriod": "date_period2>unit_sum"
            },
            "script": "(params.secondPeriod-params.firstPeriod)*100/params.firstPeriod"
          }
        },
        "retain_buckets": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "percentage": "percentage_increase"
            },
            "script": "params.percentage > 5"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a full test data in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/astefan/55a9d7f850c99d8b2832e94294c83fd4).

The result of this aggregation is giving you this:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "data_split": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "A",
          "doc_count": 6,
          "date_period1": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "unit_sum": {
              "value": 150
            }
          },
          "date_period2": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "unit_sum": {
              "value": 160
            }
          },
          "percentage_increase": {
            "value": 6.666666666666667
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "C",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "date_period1": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "unit_sum": {
              "value": 50
            }
          },
          "date_period2": {
            "doc_count": 1,
            "unit_sum": {
              "value": 70
            }
          },
          "percentage_increase": {
            "value": 40
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The idea is that you use two `filter` type of aggregations for the two date intervals. And for each you calculate a sum. Then, using a third aggregation of type `bucket_script` you calculate the percentage increase (note, though, that it will be a negative number of there is a decrease in sales for example).
Then, using yet another aggregation - of type `bucket_selector` - you keep the `product_id`s where the percentage is larger than 5%.

Comment: This looks great Andrei, i'll try this out now.